# How to edit and delete particular message from XMPP in android?

Tags: android, xmpp

I am Developing a Voip Application I am implementing an XMPP chatting functionality.i have my own jabber server to implement an XMPP service and I am using this library https://github.com/siacs/Conversations. in my android application. This library provides an all chatting functionality except delete and edit the message. Now I want to implement edit and delete a particular message from end to end-user. This library only gives to edit the last message.

Thanks in advance and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have also implemented chat using XMPP in my project, this can help you :

https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0308.html

**User sends a message with a mistake in¶**

```
<message to='juliet@capulet.net/balcony' id='bad1'>
  <body>But soft, what light through yonder airlock breaks?</body>
</message>
```

**User corrects the message and sends¶**

```
<message to='juliet@capulet.net/balcony' id='good1'>
  <body>But soft, what light through yonder window breaks?</body>
  <replace id='bad1' xmlns='urn:xmpp:message-correct:0'/>
</message>
```

**For Deletion :**

If a client or service implements message deletion, it MUST specify the ***'urn:xmpp:message-delete:0'*** feature in its service discovery information features as specified in Service Discovery (XEP-0030) [2] and the Entity Capabilities profile specified in Entity Capabilities (XEP-0115) [3].

To check your client supports deletion of message send this query :

http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/>

If response contains this ***'urn:xmpp:message-delete:0'*** then it support and you can delete message by following code :

http://legastero.github.io/customxeps/extensions/message-delete.html

```
<message to='room@muc.example.com' id='remove1'>
  <remove id='bad1' xmlns='urn:xmpp:message-delete:0'/>
</message>
```

`remove id=` is the id of message you want to delete

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I am edited the last message I am getting this type of log.....
I/System.out: Message Packet Received::::: <message type="chat" xml:lang="en" xmlns="jabber:client" id="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-91180094ddd5" from="91xxxxxxxx@switch.xxxxxxx.com/phone" to="1xxxxxxxx@switch.xxxxxxx.com/phone"><markable xmlns="urn:xmpp:chat-markers:0"/><origin-id xmlns="urn:xmpp:sid:0" id="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-91180094ddd5"/><replace xmlns="urn:xmpp:message-correct:0" id="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-a62b4584639a"/><body xmlns="jabber:client">This message is edited</body></message>

Comment: Hey, I want to delete or edit a particular random message. I am already implementing edit the last message.

Comment: For deletion I guess first your server should support deletion, like check for the option to enable deletion from software you are using for XMPP

Comment: I am using the whole conversation library and on the server-side, I am the only creation of a jabber account and sign up with the library code. now I am stuck with the library because in which there is no such method of delete and edit a particular method.

Comment: check if that support deletion by sending the xml i shared above code

Comment: I am already trying it and it does not work. thanks for helping.